# Central cross moments of independent random varibales

Tags: expected-value, moments, generalized-moments

The central cross-moments of a random vector $[X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n]$ is

$$ \mu_X(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_n) =E[(X_1-E[X_1])^{n_1}(X_2-E[X_2])^{n_2}\dots(X_n-E[X_n])^{n_n}]$$

I wish to know if $\mu_X(1,1,\dots,1)$ is zero if the $X_i$ are independent of each other. And, if possible, a proof or reference.

The fact that this is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$ (covariance) leads me to suspect that it may be valid for larger $n$.

Comment: Unless I misread your question, isn't that a direct consequence of $E(XYZ)=E(X)E(Y)E(Z)$ under mutual independence?

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thank you. I think you are right. Maths is not my field so maybe this is a very silly question. If I understood you, you mean that we can take each parentheses above as a new random variable with null expectation. For example,  $Y=X_2-E[X_2]$. Did I get you?

Comment: Yes, that was my idea indeed!